# Deny viewing list of schemas that user doesn't have access

Tags: sql-server

I have Azure SQL Server database, with large number of schemas.
I need to create user that can access only specific schema it's working but,
I still can see the list of all schemas. How can I hide the list of schemas?

I create user with this permissions:

```sql
CREATE USER someuser FOR LOGIN somelogin;  
GRANT CONNECT to someuser;
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA :: [dbo] TO someuser;
```

I tried to deny all kind of permission on schema, but without success

Comment: That a user can *see* the schema doesn't mean that they can *do* anything with them.

Comment: @ThomA Right, but I need to hide list of schemas

Comment: You can't, a list of the schemas will always be visible in `sys.schemas`. Even if that `USER` is just a member of the `public` role and has no other permissions.

Comment: This is almost certainly an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info). What are you *really* trying to achieve here? Perhaps, for example, you want a user to only be able to do *something* on a specific schema?

Comment: @ThomA Thank, you give me idea for answer:
DENY SELECT ON sys.schemas TO someuser
I still can call objects directly

Comment: Because the `USER` has been `GRANT`ed permission. A `USER` *can't* do anything on a schema unless you've given them those permissions. That includes the `dbo` schema.

Comment: Honestly **don't** mess around with permissions on system views, you can seriously mess up your database.

Comment: What purpose is hiding the list of schemas defined in the database going to do? Do you also need prevent viewing tables? This just screams of something horribly wrong.

Comment: @SeanLange We have one database for our application, each schema is dedicated to specific customer, each one will have their own database user and set of pre defined reports. We don't want customers to see whole customer list, or be able to browsing the database. They can use the tables by selecting then directly without browsing.

Comment: Do your users have direct access to the database? As in your customers can write their own queries against the database? This sounds like a really bad situation you are in.

Comment: No, but report system '(Power BI)' allow to edit source queries.